# Fatal error: start symbol does not derive any sentence

Tags: c, yacc, lex

Iam trying to develop a program for a calculator using lex and yacc. I keeping getting the following error:

```
calc.y: warning: 5 nonterminals useless in grammar [-Wother]
calc.y: warning: 8 rules useless in grammar [-Wother]
calc.y:8.1: fatal error: start symbol I does not derive any sentence
 I : E '\n' {printf("%d\n",$1);}
```

I looked at similiar problems but they had infinite recursions but this one doesn't have .

**calc.l**

```
%{
#include"y.tab.h"
%}

digits [0-9]*

%%
{digits} {return DIGITS}
%%

int yywrap()
{
}
```

**calc.y**

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>   
%}

%token DIGITS

%%
I : E '\n' {printf("%d\n",$1);}
  ;
E : E '+' F {$$ = $1 + $3;}
  | E '-' F {$$ = $1 - $3;}
  ;
F : F '*' G {$$ = $1 * $3;}
  | F '/' G {$$ = $1 / $3;}
G :'('E')' 
  | DIGITS 
  ;
%%

int main()
{
    yyparse();
}
int yyerror()
{
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know yacc, but:

- To build an `I`, you need an `E`:

  ```
  I : E '\n'
  ```
- To build an `E`, you need an `E`:

  ```
  E : E '+' F
    | E '-' F
  ```

Since there is no way to build an `E` if you don't already have one (and in the beginning you don't have anything), there is no way to build an `I` either.

Or looking at it from the other side: `E` is infinitely recursive because it always refers back to itself.

---

If we start with the lexer, we get `DIGITS` first.

`DIGITS` can be used to build a `G`.

But there's nothing we can do with a `G` because the only rules that use it (`F '*' G` and `F '/' G`) also require an `F` to proceed, and we don't have an `F`. So we're stuck.

Comment: But in the end we use the token DIGITS.So it should end there

Comment: @anoop, but you never get to the end because `E` can't derive a single `F` nor `F` a `G`.

Comment: @Anoopsaju Amended my answer.